# How to get node data when connecting two nodes in reactflow?

Tags: reactjs, react-flow

I want to retrieve the data from two nodes when I connect them in reactflow App. I want to do this in the on connect function.

I currently have this function.

```
function Flow() {
  const [elements, setElements] = useState(initialNodes);
  const [nodes, setNodes, onNodesChange] = useNodesState(initialNodes);
  const [edges, setEdges, onEdgesChange] = useEdgesState(initialEdges);
  const [isSidebarOpen, setIsSidebarOpen] = useState(true);
  //const getNodeDataById = (id: string | null) => {
  //  const node = elements.find((element) => element.id === id);
  //  return node?.data?.input || "No data found";
  //};
  const onConnect = useCallback(
    (params: Connection) => {
      // Extract the source and target node IDs from the connection parameters
      const { source, target }: string = params;

      // Retrieve node data based on the source and target node IDs from your state or data structure
      const sourceNodeData = nodes[source];
      const targetNodeData = nodes[target];

      // Log the node data to the console or perform any other operations as needed
      if (sourceNodeData && targetNodeData) {
        console.log('Source Node Data:', sourceNodeData);
        console.log('Target Node Data:', targetNodeData);
      }

      // Add the edge using the addEdge function from react-flow-renderer
      const updatedEdges = addEdge(params, edges);

      // Update the edges state with the newly created or modified edge data
      setEdges(updatedEdges);
    },
    [edges, setEdges]
  );

  const toggleSidebar = () => {
    setIsSidebarOpen(!isSidebarOpen);
  };

  const addNode = (nodeType: string) => {
    const newNode = {
      id: `dndnode_${nodes.length}`,
      type: nodeType,
      data: { label: `Node ${nodes.length + 1}` },
      position: { x: Math.random() * 400, y: Math.random() * 400 }, // Random position for demonstration
    };
    setNodes((nds) => [...nds, newNode]);
  };

  const exportToYAML = () => {
    const transformedNodes = nodes.map((node) => {
      // Extract only the desired data from each node
      const { id, data } = node;
      return { id, ...data };
    });

    const yamlContent = yaml.dump({ nodes: transformedNodes, edges });
    downloadYAML(yamlContent, "flow.yaml");
  };

  const updateNodeData = (nodeId: string, newData: any) => {
    setNodes((prevNodes) =>
      prevNodes.map((node) =>
        node.id === nodeId
          ? { ...node, data: { ...node.data, ...newData } }
          : node
      )
    );
  };

  const nodeTypes = useMemo(
    () => ({
      custom: CustomNode,
      initialDagNode: InitialDagNode,
      sftp: SftpToGcs,
      convert: (nodeProps: NodeProps) => (
        <ConvertDataFile
          {...nodeProps}
          updateNodeData={(newData) => updateNodeData(nodeProps.id, newData)}
        />
      ),
      // ... other node types ...
    }),
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    [
      /* dependencies, if any, such as updateNodeData */
    ]
  );

  return (
    <>
      <NodeSearch onAdd={addNode} />
      <div className="parent-container">
        <Sidebar
          onAddNode={addNode}
          isSidebarOpen={isSidebarOpen}
          toggleSidebar={toggleSidebar}
        />
        <div className={styles.flow}>
          <ReactFlow
            nodes={nodes}
            onNodesChange={onNodesChange}
            edges={edges}
            onEdgesChange={onEdgesChange}
            onConnect={onConnect}
            nodeTypes={nodeTypes}
            defaultEdgeOptions={defaultEdgeOptions}
            connectionLineType={ConnectionLineType.SmoothStep}
            fitView
          >
            <MiniMap />
            <Controls />
          </ReactFlow>
        </div>
        <button className={styles.yamlbutton} onClick={exportToYAML}>
          Export to YAML
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

The issue im having is that the const { source, target } = params seems to be set as nulls and cant be used as indexes when looking through my node list. Has anyone encountered or solved this problem?

Comment: Doesn't it work when you use your getNodeDataById function? It seems like the problem is that you won't get the node by calling nodes[source]. But calling getNodeDataById(source) could work.
You could also try to use getNode() from reactFlowInstance: https://reactflow.dev/api-reference/types/react-flow-instance#get-node